# How to replace the RedirectView as a POST request

Tags: spring, post, get

RedirectView always works as a GET request but there are multiple requirements in my application to use POST and hide the parameters in the url. Is there any alternative to RedirectView

Comment: Redirect is always a GET, so no. If you want to hide parameters store them in the session and retrieve on the next request.

Comment: Does RedirectView works as GET even if the original request is POST?

Comment: As stated a redirect is always a GET. A redirect is always client side basically a 302 (or 301) is returned to the client with the URL to goto.

Comment: Is there any alternative to RedirectView

Comment: There is a requirement to log the logout action in application DB. So I am redirecting to a controller with action 'logout', there I am logging the action and redirecting to 'j_spring_security_logout'. But in Spring 3.2 we have CSRF enabled and logout is no longer a GET. It has to be POST. This is my exact issue

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution to this problem:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/redirectTo", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
public ModelAndView navigate(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, @RequestParam String url,
        @RequestBody final String body, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws Exception {
    String redirectUrl = "someUrl";
    RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView();
    redirectView.setUrl(redirectUrl);
    redirectView.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
    redirectView.setHttp10Compatible(Boolean.TRUE);
    return new ModelAndView(redirectView);
}
```